# Android custom ProgressBar with custom progress

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

Is that possible to have a custom ProgressBar in Android like this:

[image]

I mean:

- Not spinning (static)
- Progress with one color and remaining area with another color
- With text in center

If that's not possible, what's the nearest result that I can have? Maybe using XML Shapes? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a standard Android component for reaching this result.

However, there is a library that you can use to achieve that effect.

Check [this library](https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel).

You can customize this component as you like and use it on your xml layouts like a Custom View.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not a native progressbar like this. Using that, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Check this library: https://github.com/wasabeef/awesome-android-ui/blob/master/pages/Progress.md. It does what you want.

Comment: Can you explain the downgrade? CircleProgress is exactly what you describe you want.